# Second x axis or x labels

Tags: python, altair

I would like to ask you if there is a way how to create a second x-axis in Altair (put the daytime on top)?

```
bar_cumm_TAGP = alt.Chart(df_TAGP_2[df_TAGP_2['simulation_date'] == '2020-10- 
15']).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('DVS:O'),
        alt.X2('day:O'),
        alt.Y(f'TAGP:Q', axis=alt.Axis(titlePadding=10, titleFontSize=14), title=""),
        alt.Color(f'TAGP:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='greens'))).properties(width=850, height=350)

line = alt.Chart(df_TAGP_2).mark_line(interpolate='basis', strokeWidth=2, color='#FB0000').encode(
alt.X('DVS'),
alt.Y('mean(TAGP)'))

alt.layer(bar_cumm_TAGP, line).resolve_scale(
x = 'independent'
)
```

My code snippet:

```
condition = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
df_TAGP_2 = pd.DataFrame({
     'day': pd.date_range('1990-01-01', freq='D', periods=10000),
     'DVS': np.random.choice(condition , 10000,),
     'TAGP': np.random.randint(4000, size=(10000)),
     'simulation_date': '2020-10-15'})
```

My result:

[image]

What I would like to see
[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have a dual x-axis in the picture. Some of the weirdness you are seeing with the different length of the top and bottom axis have been resolved in the current development version of Altair, in which you chart would look like this:

[image]

You can try it out by downloading it directly from the Altair GitHub page.

Update after question edit:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

condition = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
df_TAGP_2 = pd.DataFrame({
     'day': pd.date_range('1990-01-01', freq='D', periods=20),
     'DVS': np.random.choice(condition , 20,),
     'TAGP': np.random.randint(10, size=(20)),
     'simulation_date': '2020-10-15'})

bar_cumm_TAGP = alt.Chart(df_TAGP_2[df_TAGP_2['simulation_date'] == '2020-10-15']).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('DVS:O'),
        alt.Y(f'TAGP:Q', title=""),
        alt.Color(f'TAGP:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='greens'))).properties(width=850, height=350)

line = alt.Chart(df_TAGP_2).mark_line(interpolate='basis', strokeWidth=2, color='#FB0000').encode(
alt.X('day:O', axis=alt.Axis(labelPadding=100)),
alt.Y('mean(TAGP)'))

alt.layer(bar_cumm_TAGP, line).resolve_scale(
x = 'independent'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Ouu I see... I provided an insufficient description. I would like to see DateTime on the top of the x-axis... I've put a small improvement in description.

Comment: @LukášTůma Hmm not sure I understand fully. Do you mean that you want "day" above the chart where it says DVS now? And everything else the same? Maybe you could create a mock up using gimp/photoshop of how you want the figure to look?

Comment: Ok I am in countryside... Later I will provide you with mock up

Comment: @joelstblom I've provided the expected result to my post

Comment: @LukášTůma I included an update based on your edit. The main part is not to use X2 for the bars. This is still using altiar development version.